# How to color bar plot with bars dependent on column names in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, bar-chart

I have two data frames and a function *maxthree* which takes in a data frame and row name as an argument and plots the three highest value on the row (in a descending order) and the name of the column of three highest value.

```
    set.seed(0)
    df <- data.frame(A=c(3,2,1,4,5),B=c(1,6,3,8,4),C=c(2,1,4,8,9), D=c(4,1,2,4,6))
    row.names(df)<-c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5")

    df2 <- data.frame(E=c(2,5,6,1,4),F=c(2,4,2,5,1),G=c(5,6,2,7,3),H=c(8,2,7,4,1))
    row.names(df2)<-c("R6","R7","R8","R9","R10")

    print(df)

       A B C D
    R1 3 1 2 4
    R2 2 6 1 1
    R3 1 3 4 2
    R4 4 8 8 4
    R5 5 4 9 6

    print(df2)

        E F G H
    R6  2 2 5 8
    R7  5 4 6 2
    R8  6 2 2 7
    R9  1 5 7 4
    R10 4 1 3 1

    maxthree <- function(data, row) {
      order<-as.matrix(data[row, order(unlist(data[row, ]), decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]])
      barplot(order)
    }


    maxthree(df2, "R7")
```

[image]

I am trying to have the function *maxthree* to color each bar differently depending on the column they would be on. So, for example, if columns in df2 would be colored in a following way: E=green, F=red, G=yellow, H=blue, the bars in the previous bar graph should be yellow, green, red (in that order). I know how to color in a normal bar plot by using "col" inside barplot() but I don't know how to color in the bars in this situation since it is dependent on which columns appear on the bar plot and on the order of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with a named vector defining colors for different rows:

```
col.colors <- c(E="green", F="red", G="yellow", H="blue")

maxthree <- function(data, row) {
      order<-as.matrix(data[row, order(unlist(data[row, ]), decreasing = TRUE)[1:3]])
      order.names <- colnames(order)
      order.colors <- col.colors[order.names]
      barplot(as.vector(order), names.arg = order.names, col = order.colors)
}
maxthree(df2, "R7")
```

[image]